How to add versioning and change logging for a monorepository with several .net C# projects using the "Versionize" library?
I have a mono-repository with several projects. Version numbers are the same at start for all .net core projects.
I try to add automatic versioning and changelog with command of "Versionize" library in Package manager console (Visual Studio):
versionize --configDir currProjName1

versionize --proj-name currProjName1


that write here: https://github.com/versionize/versionize
 --proj-name                          Name of a project defined in the configuration file (for monorepos)
My .versionize config file for example in a root of project folder:
{
  "name": "currProjName1",
  "project-name": "currProjName1",
  "projectname": "currProjName1",
  "projname": "currProjName1",
  "proj-name": "currProjName1",
  "changelogAll": true,
  "changelog": {
    "header": "ChangeLog 'currProjName1'",
    "sections": [
      {
        "type": "feat",
        "section": "✨ Features",
        "hidden": false
      },
      {
        "type": "fix",
        "section": " Bug Fixes",
        "hidden": true
      },
      {
        "type": "perf",
        "section": " Performance",
        "hidden": false
      }
    ]
  }
}

As a result, I get a two different changelogs for the projects and a new version of the file after committing the changes.
But when I do this for other project, I get error 'Version 1.0.1 already exists. Please use a different version.'.
The text of the documentation talks about a common configuration file with the names of all projects. But unfortunately his example is not described.
What should I add to make this idea work?
